# how to export googleMaps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have got google Maps implemented in my Application. When I export a signed APK file of my application, the google Map isn't shown.

How to import the signed apk with google Maps?

Thanks

Comment: When you run the signed version do you get any errors (look in Logcat)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have 2 different Maps API keys - debug and release versions. So when you build release version - you have to set release key. Generally you have 2 different keystores on your machine - debug keystore and release keystore. When you build release app - you use release keystore to sign the app. This keystore needs to be used for generating relase API key.

In detail, this described [in documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Answer (score 0):

Is the key you used to request the Google Service the debug key?

When generating a signed APK you can create a new one, which would result in your services not having the correct permissions. Usually there are logging statements that would say why it is not loading.